# regex match function argument from function declaration

Tags: regex

I try to write c# application and try to use regex to match function argument from function declaration. For example, I have

```
ReturnType Condition_Check(NegativeResponseCode *ErrorCode_pt, uint8 Sid_u8)

FUNC(Std_ReturnType, DiaDcmAdapter_CODE) ProductionMode_Write
        (P2CONST(uint8, AUTOMATIC, RTE_APPL_DATA) p_Data,
        P2VAR(Dcm_NegativeResponseCodeType, AUTOMATIC, RTE_APPL_DATA) ErrorCode)

void DSDL_V(const UBYTE* abc)
```

I want to match their's argument. Example
for first function, it should return ErrorCode_pt and Sid_u8
for second function, it should return p_Data and ErrorCode
for third function, it should return abc
Not match if function don't have argument

It's easy for us with first function by use below regex

```
Condition_Check\(\w+\s+\*?(\w+)\s*,\s*\w+\s*(\w+)\s*\)
```

My test: https://regex101.com/r/thD5bR/1

and get $1 and $2 But for 2nd function and 3rd function to complicated and more over, I don't know how many argument in the function (sometime it's 1 arg, sometime 2 arg...)

Is there any best way to match function argument from function declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match your function parameters by imposing two conditions:

- `(?<=[^,][ *])` - it is preceeded by no commas and either space or star
- `(?=\)|,)` - it is followed by either a closed parenthesis or a comma

Here's the full regex:

```
(?<=[^,][ *])\w+(?=\)|,)
```

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/bQjHhI/1).